$z^n: S^1\to S^1$, $n\geq2$ is not $1$-fat.
A covering map $p:E\rightarrow B$ is called $k$-fat if there is an embedding $i: E\subset B\times\Bbb R^k$ such that $p=p_1\circ i.$
Theorem: If $B$ is a $CW$-complex of dimension $d$, any covering map over$B$ is $(d+1)$-fat.
If $z^n:S^1\to S^1$ is the covering map $z^n(e^{i\theta})=e^{i n\theta}$ which is an $n$-covering, it is $2$-fat by the theorem above.
$z^1: S^1\to S^1$ is obviously $1$-fat: Let $i: S^1\to S^1\times\Bbb R$, $i(e^{i\theta})=(e^{i\theta},0).$
On the other hand, $z^n: S^1\to S^1$ is not $1$-fat if $n\geq2.$ I couldn't write a satisfying proof of this fact. I am trying to think of a proof by picture and intermedite-value theorem comes into my mind. On the other hand, I wonder whether some other theorems can be used, e.g. Borsuk-Ulam theorem.
Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

The key is the IVT.
Let $p_1: S^1 \times \mathbb R \to S^1$ and $p_2: S^1 \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be the projections .
Assume to the contrary that there exists an embedding $i : S^1 \to S^1 \times \mathbb R$ such that $p_1 \circ i = z^n$.

For each $w \in S^1$ the intersection $F(w)$ of $i(S^1)$ with the fiber $p_1^{-1}(w) = \{w\} \times \mathbb R$ has exactly $n$ points. These are the $i$-images of the $n$-th roots of $w$.
Proof. If $i(z) \in p_1^{-1}(w)$, then $w = p_1(i(z)) = z^n$.

For each $w \in S^1$ the restriction $p_2 \mid_{p_1^{-1}(w)} : p_1^{-1}(w) \to \mathbb R$ is a bijection. Hence $p_2 \mid_{F(w)}$ is an injection.

Let $z_1,\ldots,z_n \in S^1$ be the $n$ points such that $F(1) = \{i(z_1),\ldots, i(z_n)\}$. These are the $n$-th unit roots. The $p_2(i(z_k)) \in \mathbb R$ are $n$ distinct real numbers. By a suitable choice of indices we may assume $p_2(i(z_1))  < p_2(i(z_2)) < \ldots < p_2(i(z_n))$.

Define paths $u_k : I \to S^1 \times \mathbb R, u_k(t) = i(z_ke^{2\pi i t/n})$. For each $t$ one has $\{u_1(t), \ldots, u_n(t)\} = F(e^{2\pi i t})$. The $u_k$ are uniquely determined by their initial points $u_k(0) = i(z_k) \in F(1)$.
Proof. Since $i$ is injective and the $z_ke^{2\pi i t/n}$ are pairwise distinct, the $u_k(t)$ are pairwise distinct. Moreover $p_1(u_k(t)) = p_1(i(z_ke^{2\pi i t/n})) = (z_ke^{2\pi i t/n})^n = 2\pi i t$.

The assignment $i(z_k) = u_k(0) \mapsto u_k(1)$ is a bijection from $F(1)$ onto itself.
This is obvious because $e^{2 \pi i 1} = 1$.

The bijection in 4. has no fixed point.
Proof. For each $k$ the map $v_k :  I \to S^1, v_k(t) = z_ke^{2\pi i t/n}$ is an injection. Hence $u_k = i \circ v_k$ is an injection so that $i(z_k) = u_k(0) \ne u_k(1)$.

For all $t$ one has $p_2(u_k(t)) < p_2(u_{k+1}(t))$ for $k = 1,\ldots, n-1$.
Proof. By the convention in 3. this is true for $t = 0$. Assume that $p_2(u_k(t)) \ge p_2(u_{k+1}(t))$ for some $t, k$. Then by the IVT there exists $\tau \in (0,t]$ such that
$p_2(u_k(t)) = p_2(u_{k+1}(t))$. But then $u_k(\tau) = u_{k+1}(\tau)$ which is impossible because in that case the set $\{u_1(\tau), \ldots, u_n(\tau)\}$ would have less than $n$ elements.

In particular $p_2(u_1(1)) < p_2(u_2(1)) < \ldots < p_2(u_n(1))$. Since $\{p_2(u_1(1)),\ldots, p_2(u_n(1)) \} = p_2(F(1)) = \{p_2(i(z_1)), \ldots, p_2(i(z_n)\}$, 3. implies $p_2(u_k(1)) = p_2(i(z_k)$. By 2. we conclude that the bijection in 4. is the identity which contradicts 6.



Here's a solution using winding numbers.
Consider the deformation retraction $H\colon (S^1 \times \mathbb{R}) \times I \to S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$, $H((z, x), t) = (z, (1 - t)x)$ of $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ onto $S^1 \times \{0\}$. Assuming that there is an embedding $i\colon S^1 \to S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ with $\mathrm{pr}_{S^1} \circ i = z^n$, this $i$ is thus in fact homotopic to the map $z \mapsto (z^n, 0)$ via $H$.
Note now that $S^1 \times \mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ via a homeomorphism that takes $S^1 \times \{0\}$ to $S^1 = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| = 1\}$. Our previous observation then implies that the winding number of $i$ around $0 \in \mathbb{C}$ is precisely $n$. On the other hand, $i$ is an embedding, so its winding number around 0 can only be 0, 1, or $-1$ (by the Jordan-Schoenflies theorem), which gives the desired contradiction when $|n| > 1$.
